# Ruby on rails, scriptaculous (visual_effect) inside facebox not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous, facebox

I use facebox to display a lightbox popup inside my RoR 2.3.9 application to display a :partial.
Inside this partial, I want to toggle (or any other visual effect that would go from one div to another inside the partial) from several steps for a form_for.

When I do the following for both buttons (step 1, 2...):

```
 <%= link_to_function "Keeps", 
    visual_effect(:fade, "step1", :duration => 0.2) +
    visual_effect(:fade, "step2", :duration => 0.2) +
    visual_effect(:grow, "step3", :duration => 0.2) %>
```

which show or hide the divs:

```
<div id="step1" class="feed_container">
     content
</div>

<div id="step2" class="feed_container" style="display:none">
     content
</div>

<div id="step3" class="feed_container" style="display:none">
     content
</div>
```

It works in the "normal pages" but doesn't in the popup. If I click the go to step2 button for example, it doesn't do anything. However, if I close the popup and open it again, it'll be in step 2.

Any thoughts on how I could get this working in ruby on rails?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prototype helpers were deprecated in Rails 3. You might be better off adopting an unobtrusive Javascript approach from now itself, since it'd be useful to pick up the know-how in the long-term.

Your browser (Firefox with the Firebug extension, or Chrome - Right click -> Inspect Element) should point out any and all errors in the generated javascript in the bottom right corner. Those errors probably hold the key to what's going wrong.